# How to solve this convex problem heuristically?

Tags: integer-programming, convex-optimization, heuristics, network-flow

I have the following problem

$$\max_{X_{i,j},i\in N_{U},j\in N_{B}}\sum_{i=1}^{N_U}\sum_{j=1}^{N_B}R_{i,j}X_{i,j}$$
$$\text{subject to}$$
$$a_{\min}\le\sum_{j=1}^{N_B}X_{i,j}\le a_{\max}, \forall i$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N_U}X_{i,j}\le b_{\max}, \forall j$$

It is a convex problem,b ut I need a heuristic approach to solve this.

Here, $R$ is a knowm matrix. $X$ is a binary matrix. $a_{\min}$, $a_{\max}$ and $b_{\max}$ are also know. and positive

Any suggestions

Comment: Be careful when you edit and delete part of the question which has been answered. Instead, I suggest to add an "EDIT" paragraph below and specify that you would like to ignore a constraint (instead of deleting it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have removed the range constraints, the problem decomposes by $j$ and can be solved optimally for each $j$ by a greedy algorithm: set $X_{i,j}=1$ for the $b_\max$ largest (positive) values of $R_{i,j}$.

Comment: the constraint was deleted mistakenly. I still have the same problem and the same constraints.

Comment: of course, I am able to solve it optimally using some solver. But I need a heuristic solution.

Comment: OK, then you can still start with the greedy algorithm and then try to repair the resulting solution if needed.  If you exceed $a_\max$ for some $i$, change some (possibly more than one) $X_{i,j}$ from $1$ to $0$.  If you are below $a_\min$ for some $i$, try to change some (possibly more than one) $X_{i,j}$ from $0$ to $1$ without exceeding $a_\max$ or $b_\max$.

Answer (score 9):

This is a *minimum cost flow problem* in the bipartite graph $G=(V,A)$ with $V=N_U \cup N_B$.

Add a source node and link it to each vertex $v\in N_U$. On each of these arcs, constrain the flow to be in the range $[a_{min},a_{max}]$. Note that if $a_{min} > |N_B|$ the problem is infeasible.

Likewise with a sink node, that you link to each vertex $v \in N_B$, and constrain the flow such that it does not exceed $b_{max}$.

Then,  on edges $(i,j) \in A$, add a cost $-R_{ij}$, a capacity $Q_{ij}=1$, and find a minimum cost flow in this graph.

Not only is this problem convex : it can be solved in polynomial time with the above approach. Are you sure you want a heuristic when you have a free optimal solution ? I guess if you really want a heuristic for such problems you can checkout for example [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6381).